# jQuery.noConflict and how to use it

Tags: jquery

i try to use `jQuery.noConflict()` but in window.load function i get a "$ is not a function" error.

my code:

```
jQuery.noConflict();

jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    /** Dropdown Menu **/
    $('ul.tabs li:has(ul)').bind("click", function() {
        $(this).find('ul').show('normal');
        //event.stopPropagation();
    });
    $('ul.tabs li').bind("mouseleave", function() {
        $(this).find('ul').hide('normal');
        //event.stopPropagation();
    });
});

jQuery(window).load(function($) {
    $('#container').fadeIn('normal');
});
```

if i use jQuery instead of '$' it works fine, but is it possible to continue use the '$'?
anyone knows/understand what is wrong with this?
thanks!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The first part of your code works because jQuery's `$` object is always passed to `ready` handlers. However, the same behavior does not apply to the `load` handlers.

If you do not want to replace `$` with `jQuery` in the body of your `load` handler, you can capture that variable in a closure:

```
(function($) {
    $(window).load(function() {
        $("#container").fadeIn("normal");
    });
})(jQuery);
```

Alternatively, you can register your `load` handler inside your `ready` handler, where `$` is correctly bound.

Answer (score 3):

If you use `jQuery.noConflict()`, `$` is not defined anymore for using with jQuery.

You have to use `jQuery()` instead of `$()`

As stated in the [doc](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/):

> Many JavaScript libraries use $ as a function or variable name, just
>   as jQuery does. In jQuery's case, $ is just an alias for jQuery, so
>   all functionality is available without using $. If we need to use
>   another JavaScript library alongside jQuery, **we can return control of
>   $ back to the other library with a call to $.noConflict()**

---

Thansk for the comment.

If you want to use the `$` parameter

Comment: If you looked at the code you see he is put in the $ as parameter of the $(document).ready() function. Within the function you can have access to the $...

Comment: Indeed ! Thanks for noting it.